# What is this pattern/idiom? What are the benefits?

Tags: java, design-patterns, idioms

I see this idiom a lot in the code base I work in, which is essentially:

> Interface -> Abstract class that defines getters/setters -> Implementations

For example:

```
interface Foo{
    void doSomethingA();
    void doSomethingB();
}

abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo{
    protected int x;
    protected String y;
    int getX(){ return x;}
    void setX(int x){ this.x = x;}
    String getY(){ return y;}
    void setY(String y){ this.y = y;}
}
//One or more concrete classes extending AbstractFoo
```

Is there a name for this? The only benefit I can see is that classes extending AbstractFoo don't need to re-implement their getters and setters.

Comment: Perhaps Inheritance and abstraction by `Foo`?

Answer (score 6):

It's *not* a design pattern.

The interface is obvious: every class that implements an interface has to implement its methods - no questions asked.

An abstract class can provide default behavior for every method if it wishes.  So yes, it's for the convenience of subclass developers.  Remember, the person who writes the abstract class is likely to provide at least one concrete subclass, so the benefits accrue to them.

Getters and setters are not the point.  Any good IDE can generate them for you.  The feature is more meaningful for complex default behavior.

Look at how Joshua Bloch used this idiom to great success in the `java.util` package when he designed the Collection API.

Answer (score 0):

I think it goes by the name "Abstract Implementation". You would not just put getters and setters into the abstract class, but anything that all implementations of the interface would likely have in common.  The idea is to make it easier to provide implementations of the interface by taking care of the common stuff in advance.  Implementors might still choose to not extend the abstract base class if they want to implement stuff in a completely different way.